# How to make $.post requests run in order with using ajax alternative

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to execute $.post requests synchronously? I have the following code:

```
function loadTest() {

var questionIDs = [];

var count = 0;

console.log("getting test");
$.post("db.php", function(data) {
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    var questionCount = obj.length;

    console.log(obj);

    while (count != questionCount) {

        questionIDs.push(obj[count].id);
        count++;
    }
    console.log(questionIDs);

    // $('#question').html(obj[0].question);
});

$.post("getChoices.php", {
    IDs: questionIDs
}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    console.log(obj);

    while (q < 3) {
        console.log("question");
        var w = 1;
        while (w < 5) {

            console.log(obj[q][w]);
            w++;
        }
        q++;
    }

    // $('#question').html(obj[0].question);
});

}
```

Due to the $.post functions running asycnchronously, the variable questionIDs will be empty when being sent. Is there a possible solution for this that doesn't require changing from $.post to ajax? I've tried various solutions on here but I can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: Wrap second call in a function and call it from inside of the first closure after the moment when you've got access to `questionIDs`. You can also put second function inside of `.done` part.

Comment: You could do something like this.. 

`var res = '';
$.post().done(function(response) { res = response; }).then($.post().done(function(response1) { alert(res + " " + response1 }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you make the second request once the first one has been responded. Put the second request inside the first request callback. Like this:

```js
function loadTest() {

  var questionIDs = [];

  var count = 0;

  console.log("getting test");
  $.post("db.php", function(data) {
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    var questionCount = obj.length;

    console.log(obj);

    while (count != questionCount) {

      questionIDs.push(obj[count].id);
      count++;
    }
    console.log(questionIDs);

    //      $('#question').html(obj[0].question);

    $.post("getChoices.php", {
      IDs: questionIDs
    }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

      console.log(obj);

      while (q < 3) {
        console.log("question");
        var w = 1;
        while (w < 5) {

          console.log(obj[q][w]);
          w++;
        }
        q++;
      }

      // $('#question').html(obj[0].question);
    });
  });
}
```